# Animation effects on dynamically loaded content - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, load, fade

```
$(function() {
 $("a").hover(
  function() {
   $(this).animate({color: "blue"}, 400);
  }, function() {
   $(this).animate({color: "white"}, 400);
 })
 $(".left").fadeOut("slow").load("created.php").fadeIn("slow");
})
```

I want the links (a's) from the created.php page to have the hover effect. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use `live` to bind handlers. That way, any new 'a' loaded in the page will also get the hover effect.

```
$(function() {
     $("a").live(
     { mouseenter: function() {
             $(this).animate({color: "blue"}, 400);
          }, 
       mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).animate({color: "white"}, 400);
          }
     })
     $(".left").fadeOut("slow").load("created.php").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

**Note:** With `live`, `hover` takes only one handler. Alternative is to specify `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers.

Comment: Oh nice didn't know hover existed in live yet.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: It exists but takes a single handler. You need to check the event type to see which code path to take: `event.type == "mouseover"`. This was added in v1.4.2.

Comment: @Siddhant Sutar: Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [jquery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

```
 $("a").live( {mouseover: function() {
    // do something on mouseover
  },
mouseout: function() {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```